# Removing little gap on left side Chart JS

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I don't know how to remove space on left side which you can see on the image. I tried things like aspectRatio: 1 but doesn't work.

[image]

Here's the current config

```
const config = {
  type: "line",
  data: dataSets,
  options: {
    responsive: false,
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    elements: {
      point: { radius: 0 },
      line: {
          tension: 0,
      },
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        type: "time",
        time: {
          unit: "day",
        },
        ticks: {
          display: false,
        },
        gridLines: {
          tickMarkLength: 1,
          color: "#d8d8d8",
          zeroLineColor: "#d8d8d8",
        },
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          display: false,
        },
      }],
    },
    legend: {
      display: false,
    },
  },
};
```

Comment: Tried wrapping in css div with margin -ve ? :D

Comment: @DhananjaiPai everything must be aligned so CSS negative margin is not an option here.